# Connect autodesk forge to inventor

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

How can i create a configurator using forge and inventor without Ilogic?

i'm search a way to do it on the net but no result.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/developers_guide/overview/) is what you're looking for. At the moment the only supported "automation engine" is AutoCAD, but additional products will be added over time, incl. Inventor. I can't provide more details at this point, but I'd strongly suggest to check out announcements from Autodesk University next week (Nov 12 - Nov 16, 2018), and to keep an eye on our [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog).

Comment: okay thanx for the answer, and how can i make a configurator in forge? i can't use configurator360 (instructions)

Comment: Today, you cannot make a configurator in Forge. Once Inventor is made available in the Design Automation API, you'll be able to create any plugin you want using the Inventor C# APIs and basically run them in the cloud.

Comment: thank you for the answer i'll be patient. another thing,i saw your youtube video about "disconnected workflows" how you did it?

Comment: You're welcome :) The video was made for this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows. You'll find all the details there. Cheers!

Comment: cool! thank you very much!! can we keep in touch if i have other questions?

Comment: Sure! We typically use Stack Overflow, or an email (forge [dot] help [at] autodesk [dot] com) as our main channels of communication so that my colleagues see and can answer your questions as well.